# Why does a null pointer to a non virtual class works? (see included code)

Tags: c++

They both compile.

I do not understand why the method works even though the pointer is set to NULL.
...and then, the virtual one does not. (it crashes at run-time)

THE CODE:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Person {
public:
    void PrintHello() { 
    printf("Hello \n\n"); 
    }

    ~Person() {}
};

class Student {
public:
    virtual void PrintHello() {
    printf("hello");
    }

    virtual ~Student() {
    }
};


int main() {

Person* p = NULL;
    p->PrintHello();

    Student* s = NULL;
    s->PrintHello();

    return 0;
}
```

...
thanks a lot.

Comment: Because the function code is there even if the object is not. Without the object the vtable pointer will be undefined so virtual functions will not work. Such code exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: OK I see now that there is a duplicate. I did not find it in the search, sorry.

and thanks also to Galik.

Comment: [None of this works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43fe8bb6fa866f90)